# iPad UISplitViewController multiple root views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am developing for iPad and have created a standard UISplitViewController application using the template provided in Xcode - a standard UITableView on the left and a detail view on the right.

I have modified the template so that when a user selects a table cell from the left view it pushes a new table view in it's place (still on the left side).  This works without issue, but I would like to be able to update the existing detail view from the new table view - kinda like how Apple's Mail application works.

*- I am not trying to create multiple views on the detail view (right hand side) - I've read the documentation and seen the sample code provided by Apple.*

I read/followed many tutorials, but can't seem to get this relatively simple view hierarchy to work.

More detail:-

Using `detailViewController.detailItem = @"Test";` in the RootView didSelectTableRowAtIndexPath delegate method updates the Detail view label.  Using the exact same code in the newly pushed Table View does not update the label - am I missing a reference point or something??

Since posting I've tried to use protocols & delegates to update a label on the detail view.  The label updates correctly when changed from the Root View using the new methods, however, when I push a new view onto the root view (left hand side) I can no longer update the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point after creating the RootViewController (or maybe even in a custom init method) you are setting the delegate for the DetailViewController, its a common mistake that when a new rootViewController is pushed onto the NavController that you forget to set the delgate again.

You probably are creating a new controller in the:

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

method and recording/incrementing the level of the new controller before you push it onto the navController. After you create this new controller, set the delegate again.

```
newRootController.myDelegate = self.myDelegate;
```

Before you do this If you NSLog the delegate just before you use it, you will probably find its nil.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked a charm!  I had already set the delegate when pushing the new view, but I was creating a new instance rather than referencing the existing delegate. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try the viewControllers property of your UISplitViewController

> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray
>
> *viewControllers Discussion The array in this property must contain exactly
>   two view controllers. The view
>   controllers are presented
>   left-to-right in the split view
>   interface when it is in a landscape
>   orientation. Thus, the view controller
>   at index 0 is displayed on the left
>   side and the view controller at index
>   1 is displayed on the right side of
>   the interface.
>
> The first view controller in this
>   array is typically hidden when the
>   device is in a portrait orientation.
>   Assign a delegate object to the
>   receiver if you want to coordinate the
>   display of this view controller using
>   a popover.

Comment: As far as I can tell the viewControllers property of UISplitViewController is used to assign view controllers to the view (!).  I think my issue here is to do with delegation or protocols.  No matter what I try I cannot seem to get it to work... any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please beware of the detailViewController! You have to pass this instance variable to your new root view. So something like this:

```
newRootViewController.detailViewController = self.detailViewController
```

Otherwise your new root view will never know about the detailView. For your new root(table)view you have to do things like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class DetailViewController;

    @interface VorhersageTable : UIViewController {
        UITableView *vorhersageTableView;
        DetailViewController *detailViewController;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *vorhersageTableView;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
    @end
```

to declare the property of the detailViewController in your new class.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your RootViewController.didselectRow, before you push the second table (e.g SubRoot)

```
SubRoot *subController = [[SubRoot alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubRoot" bundle:nil];
subController.detailViewController = self.detailViewController;
```

And create the SubRoot.h and SubRoot.m similar to RootViewController.

```
@class DetailViewController;
@interface SubRoot : UITableViewController {
    DetailViewController *detailViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)  DetailViewController *detailViewController;
@end
```

then synthesize detailViewController.

Hope it helps.